# Moving Mouse rapidly in/out of container causes unwanted jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="img-meta">
        <div class="img-meta-link meta-icon"><a class='meta-link' href="#"><i class="icon-link"></i></a></div>
        <div class="img-meta-img meta-icon"><a class='meta-link' href="#"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

And Here is the jQuery

```
jQuery(".featured-thumb").hover(function() {
        jQuery('.img-meta').slideDown(600,'easeOutBounce', function() { 
            jQuery('.img-meta-link').css('margin-right','50px');
            jQuery('.img-meta-link').animate({'margin-right':'0px'},500);
        });
    },
        function() {
        jQuery('.img-meta-link').animate({'margin-right':'50px'},500);
        //jQuery('.img-meta-link').css('margin-right','50px');
        jQuery('.img-meta').fadeOut('fast');
        jQuery('.img-meta-link').stop(true,false);  
    });
```

What I want to do is, make the `img-meta` slidedown, and the `meta-icon` to fade in after the slide down.

I am able to do this perfectly. But, when i move the mouse rapidly in and out of the container i do not see any slide down effect. Only, the `meta-icon` fade in and out again and again, the no. of times i moved the mouse over the container.

I have implemented the `.stop()` in the end, to avoid it. But, it doesn't happen. Anyone can explain this?

Comment: Looks ok here. What version of jQuery are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/ErwtP/

Comment: Also, you're using the `easeOutBounce` fx, which requires the jQuery UI library aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the jQuery .hoverIntent() plugin. HoverIntent puts a slight delay on the hover event so that it only fires if the user is intentionally hovering over the target as opposed to inadvertently mousing over it for a split second while moving the mouse somewhere else on the page.